# Does "contribute to global warming" mean to increase or to reduce global warming?

Tags: meaning

In an [IELTS Reading passage](http://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Reading_6_Passage_1.htm):

> In answer to the final question about the importance of rainforest conservation, the majority of children simply said that we need rainforests to survive. **Only a few of the pupils (6%) mentioned that rainforest destruction may contribute to global warming.** This is surprising considering the high level of media coverage on this issue. Some children expressed the idea that the conservation of rainforests is not important.

Does "contribute to global warming" mean to increase or to reduce global warming?

Comment: Are you confused because you believe 'contribute' has a positive meaning, but increasing global warming is a negative thing to do? Would you explain a little more why you're confused please?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I didn't vote, but maybe it's just because the question is clear and well-formatted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -  is  a NNL expected to have  the same understanding of a term as experience native speakers have?

Comment: @ColleenV I thought "contribute" would be some positive meaning.

Comment: Would you [edit] your answer and explain what you were thinking? It helps us write better answers if we understand why you're confused.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you look at [the first definition in a learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/contribute) you find positive examples like "contribute to a charity" and I can see why it might be confusing. Yes, if you scroll down the second definition obviously fits better to a fluent speaker, but I don't know if that's the case for someone still learning. I think the up-votes indicate something is interesting about the question, so I'd like to see if we can salvage it.

Comment: @ColleenV I've just realized, "contribute to" is a fixed expression, an idiom, you can "contribute money / your time" but you do not "contribute to money / your time". Instead, one or more factors **contribute to** (i.e. help create or cause) **an end result**. But I still don't understand why the OP thought *contribute* might mean "reduce".

Answer (score 6):

"Contribute to" refers to facts or behaviours that may   *increase* the global warming.

***[Contribute to](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contribute)***:

> - to be an important factor in; help to cause:
>
>   - *A sudden downpour contributed to the traffic jam.*

Dictionary.com

- To express the opposite concept, the sentence should say: .."rainforest destruction may contribute to the reduction of global warming" (however illogical that may sound).

Answer (score 1):

Contributing to global warming means making it worse. It "helps to cause" global warming.

If you contribute ideas, or contribute money, you add those things. It may help you students to understand it in a different context.